# Can I animate a div that has overflow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone explain me how I can make a step indicator that has overflow-x in CSS slide to left when next item gets active. I need this on small devices. On big screens is ok.

```css
/*Current CSS:*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
.test-step-indicator{
  font-size: 1em;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: overlay;
  white-space: nowrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test-step-indicator">
<a class="test-step-indicator-item test-step-indicator-item-active" href="#" data-step="0">1. Device</a>
<a class="test-step-indicator-item test-step-indicator-item-active" href="#" data-step="1">2. Brand</a>
<a class="test-step-indicator-item" href="#" test-data-step="2">3. Phone</a>
<a class="test-step-indicator-item" href="#" test-data-step="3">4. Repairs</a>
<a class="test-step-indicator-item" href="#" test-data-step="4">5. Service</a>
<a class="test-step-indicator-item" href="#" test-data-step="5">6. Details</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Please add a snippet with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi please I don’t understand what you mean. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Click the link on the word MCVE from my previous comment. When editing, you should see a paper with "<>" written on it, to the right of "{}" and the image button. That button is the snippet button. Add a snippet that satisfies an MCVE.

Comment: There also versions of stackoverflow for many different languages. Try visiting those.

Comment: I am from the Netherlands. I understand and can read very good English but not MCVE.

Comment: Please check. I have edited for you!

Comment: Yes, you should be to animate a slide or scroll. What animation action are you looking to perform? You should be able to animate most CSS properties.

Comment: Just like slide to left off the screen when an item gets active

Comment: @Dedurex What does "slide to the left off screen" mean? Show a before-and-after, with a mention of where someone has to click to make that before-and-after happen.